# The Fancy and Amazing April Fools question

Tags: discussion, fun, april-fools

I like simplicity. I like clear designs.
I like Stack Overflow.

But today, SO was offline and returned with this brand new, ugly... definitely new logo.

[image: sparkling]

So what's this logo all about? That's no real April fool... Okay, now everybody knows, it's the April fool. But is it the only one? Are there any more? Or are you paralyzed by all these unicorns and glitter?

And what the hey is "Cornify"? The [image: cornify] button is funny. Until you cannot click any link... I could play with it all the time :)

[image]

> **Related**
>   [What question would you have asked as an April Fool?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8790/what-question-would-you-have-asked-as-an-april-fool)

Comment: I was just about to ask this question. No idea. Must be an April's fool joke.

Comment: Closing voting: It's the same discussion as on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698430/what-question-would-you-have-asked-as-an-april-fool Just 24 hours :)

Comment: I vote on closing too. The less we pay attention to this, the more fun it is to make fun of Jeff Atwood for the horrible joke.

Comment: It's great, it's great!

Comment: I tagged this thread as the official since its CW and people are talking about the ponies.

Comment: That was my intention, Ólaf, I just wanted to attract attention with this title in the first minute :)

Comment: :D I hope there are more things to discover

Comment: Don't shock me with "closed", Ian! That's unfair! That was the real April fool

Comment: I don't mind a little joke.  It is April Fool's Day after all, but this just reminds me of Slashdot circa 2006!

Comment: Needs more favicon.

Comment: I love horses, best of all the animals!

Comment: you've been uni-cornified!

Comment: I'm kind of surprised of the closing reason. Where is the original of this question? Exact duplicate? Come on, it's just fun.

Comment: I second guerda. FFS the sites got cornify on it!

Comment: Look, programming is srs bsns, k? You're not allowed to laugh which is why this has been closed.

Comment: This is definitely not an exact duplicate.  If it is to be closed, it shouldnt be for exact dup

Comment: Who marked this as offensive? Geez!! Some people should take themselves far less seriously.

Comment: hahaha pretty cool April fools joke, my daughter would love this ability on all web pages

Comment: @curtisk - You can have this on any website visit http://www.cornify.com/ for instructions. (Even makes reading more news about the economy bearable!)

Comment: Wilfred: Even boring company pages are wonderful, brilliant, amazing with some unicorns :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What question would you have asked as an April Fool?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8790/what-question-would-you-have-asked-as-an-april-fool)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

OMG **PWNIES**!

Comment: Sigh, "its a pwny!" was a scrimmage name one of my best e-buds used (Halo PC).

Answer (score 41):

"April Fools Joke"? THAT'S WHAT THEY SAID ABOUT GMAIL!!

Answer (score 36):

How beautiful! :P

[image: Stackoverflow is cornified]

Comment: It is pictures of cute cats now instead.

Answer (score 33):

The stuff is awesome!  It's all glittery and silly and great!  Cornify gives you unicorns and kitty cats and happy fonts and messages!  Every day should be April 1!

[I assume this is a April 1 joke. http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-sparkles.gif](http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-sparkles.gif)

Comment: YEAH!!!!...then no more taxes....

Comment: Was about to comment on that, but the unicorns hide the lines.

Answer (score 22):

I really like this button. It's totally senseless but funny. Really funny.

Comic Sans MS + glitter + pink colour = **AMAZING**

That is Web 1.0 (animated gifs) + Web 2.0 (interactive stuff like clicking). So it's the *Web 3.0*

I'd love to see this everytime, per default! :)

Answer (score 15):

So after pressing 'cornify' 100 times, I was really hoping to earn a 'hidden' April Fool's badge, but no dice.  Maybe I need to press it 1000 times?

In addition to all the obvious fun stuff, I am hoping to find at least one easter egg.  'tis the season!

Comment: +1 oh yeah.. have to have an easter egg somewhere!

Answer (score 11):

Seems to come from http://www.cornify.com/

Comment: Hm, some of the pics have graphicsarcade.com logos at the bottom, too.

Comment: cornification ftw!

Answer (score 11):

**C**omponent-**O**rientated **R**estful **N**otation **I**nverse **F**unctional **Y**adayada...

Answer (score 10):

This isn't fooling anyone! The sparkles are taking over and everything will soon become cute and sparkly and bright! It was done on April Fool's simply for us to "let it slide"! We're doomed! We're all **DOOMED!!!**

**EDIT:** Being paranoid does not mean they're not after me!

Answer (score 10):

Who else clicked cornify on a post that was not their own, just in case?

Answer (score 8):

OMG PONIES and rainbows!!! AWESOME!!!

Answer (score 5):

My Little Pony!!!  Can we keep the 'corn' please Uncle Jeff?!?

Answer (score 5):

I say it's about time for us to go back to the **expert-sex-change.com**

Answer (score 4):

```
--- cornify.js  2009-04-01 03:28:44.000000000 -0400
+++ ludicrouscorny.js   2009-04-01 03:26:54.000000000 -0400
@@ -65,7 +65,8 @@ cornify_add = function() {
                head.appendChild(css);
        }
        cornify_replace();
    }   
+    cornify_add(); 
 }

 cornify_replace = function() {
    // Replace text.
    var hc = 6;
    var hs;
```

Answer (score 4):

A collection of april fools jokes:

[Tech Crunch](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/04/01/april-fools-youtube-flails-amazon-cloud-computing-in-a-blimp-3d-chrome-browsing-google-master-ai/)

Answer (score 3):

I love the new Cornify button... I'll be clicking that next time my correct answer gets downvoted!
[Shame it doesn't work in IE6]

Comment: @guerda - LOLz... and I got you with [closed] ha ha :p

Answer (score 2):

yeah yeah yeah, the more you click, the better it gets!!! thanks stackoverflow for making my day :D hahahaha :P

'Magical x answers' haha :)

Answer (score 2):

[I love horses!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEImD_r6D8o)

Answer (score 2):

**The Fancy and Amazing April Fools thread?**

...why do I have a feeling that all answers to this question will be similar to all the forums posts I've seen around the Internet whenever its April 1?

...Its the start of StackOverflow's downfall into an ordinary forum!

---

```
<insert sig here>
```

Answer (score 2):

OMG i hate those things -.-
I hope that is just for today

Answer (score 2):

Can we get a list of people who tried to close this thread. Ban the killjoys ;)

Answer (score 2):

Purpose of cornify:

Wait till colleague walks away from PC.

Navigate to SO and fill screen with rainbows and unicorns.

Go around telling random people how you saw some weird stuff on your colleague's screen.

Answer (score 2):

I hope there wont be a counter showing who clicked cornify the most!

Answer (score 2):

I got Rick Rolled. :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Obviously an april fools joke.

Comment: Actually this answer was originally refering to the first title asking what is wrong with SO. Now, the answer doesn't make sense since they've edited the title. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I get the little red crosses across my screen as Works Websense blocks it as freeware.

"Reason: The Websense category "Freeware and Software Download" is filtered.

URL: [http://www.cornify.com/getacorn.php?file=unicorn_7.gif&url=http://stackoverflow. com/questions]

Nice idea though.

Comment: :( Post it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553523/what-is-the-most-frustrating-restriction-your-it-department-has-ever-put-on-you-o

Answer (score 1):

That's not a horse... thar's a unicorn.. ugh you call yourself progrimmers... dun ya study fantasy?

Answer (score 0):

Click on Cornify to see what it does :D

Answer (score 0):

This is, like, totally sparkling.

Answer (score 0):

Great "setup" (possibly), too, on the last podcast

http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4048.html

Jeff and Joel talk about 'flashing' and animated gifs and how much they hate them around 7:15-8:30.

Comment: yes - and what did we all learn? that as long as we're not using Chrome we can stop it just by pressing Escape. but thats no fun. good job i'm using chrome

Comment: Yes, or with Opera on "Animated images" off by default, I had no clue what they were talking about :P

Answer (score 0):

Oh gosh, I feel so embarrassed - I went and complained about cornify on [uservoice](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/152397-get-rid-of-cornify)...

**DOH!!**

(blushes profusely)

Answer (score 0):

So '[RAID issues](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/tuesday-outage-its-raid-tastic/)' was just a red herring as to why the site was down this morning? They were busy tweaking unicorns?

Look : [outsourcingunicorns.com](http://www.outsourcingunicorns.com/) is still available !!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possibly the most awesomest button I have ever seen.

Unicorns ftw

Answer (score 0):

Those [quotes](http://www.cornify.com/quotes) are hilarious! :-)

http://www.cornify.com/quotes

Answer (score 0):

Disappointingly non-original, as a takeoff on "Pinkdot" of several years ago.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation has gone down to 1 because I posted a -ve comment about the April Fool.

Sorry, if I'd known merkans were using the site, I'd have put "Just Kidding" at the end in 80pt bold.

Frankly the #g20 tweets are where it's at today

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23g20+OR+G20

Comment: I took four arrows in the back for saying, "This is why I disable javascript!" Fortunately the question got removed before I took any more damage :)

Answer (score 0):

As programmers, please support [SaveIE6](http://www.saveie6.com/)

http://www.saveie6.com/

Do not forget to try downloading it!

Answer (score 0):

If I close my eyes I see unicorns now -.-

Answer (score 0):

[sigh] I won't be able to get my Cornification on today since cornify is blocked at work. I get those lovely broken images on the screen instead. Talk about double the April Fools action!

Answer (score 0):

Hah, I didn't know it changed the font to Comic Sans till I saw the screenshot, because I always purge that font from all my computers.

Answer (score 0):

Er it's now the 2nd of April and that annoying  is still up there

Comment: A new downtime will come and purge the unicorns!!