# Arrow next to username shows as empty block, not as arrow in IE8 and Firefox

Tags: support, firefox, internet-explorer-8

[image: screenshot]

In IE 8.6007.18702, the arrow next to the username shows as a DLE type block. In Firefox it shows correctly as an arrow.

UPDATE: I have the font that Jeff references below, and the issue still exists. So it's not my OS nor lack of fonts. I am using Office 2003. Perhaps the arrow should be changed to an image instead of a 17 pixel font character that may or may not be recognized. On Vista Home Premium using Firefox, the character is not shown at all.

EDIT:
Image from Firefox 6.0.2:

[image: firefox]

Comment: Are those... ears, at bottom right?

Comment: It appears as though some animals are creeping into your picture there.

Comment: @Popular: Catified baby!

Comment: I've got the same version of IE as you do, on XP, and I'm seeing an arrow. Perhaps your encoding settings are off?

Comment: Catify? Pfft! What a ripoff. *[Cornify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20477/the-fancy-and-amazing-april-fools-question)* was better. =P

Comment: What do you see if you paste this in your address bar? `javascript:$(".profile-triangle").css("font-family","Arial")`

Comment: @YOU: [object Object]

Comment: hum, strange, how about this? `javascript:(function(){$(".profile-triangle").css("font-family","Arial")})()`

Comment: @YOU: Nothing happens.

Comment: I just tried IE8 in Win7 and I see the arrow.

Comment: I get the same effect in Android webkit on Droid 2 Global.

Comment: Those ears are the debugging team! They were already checking the issue before it was reported on MSO.

Answer (score 5):

Windows XP has a limited, non-full unicode range default system font out of the box.

You can obtain a unicode version of the default font by installing any of the products listed on this page (scroll to the bottom) …

http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1081

… or by obtaining this font by other means.*

Generally speaking, if you have installed Office 2003 or later on XP, you will have the full unicode set of fonts.

<sub><sub>* Or, y'know, upgrade to an operating system that was not released ten years ago</sub></sub>

Comment: Jeff, there are many of us who still use XP for various reasons. For instance, for me its because I use Windows XP Embedded (which is still a viable and legal OS). So if you are going to make a snarky smartass comment, you might as well make it in the normal font size.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it works in IE for now, I also occasionally use IE8 for Stack Overflow, and I always get the little block.  I let the mods know, but hadn't checked back into IE to see if it had been fixed.

You may also notice that the highlighting on the new reputation page doesn't work right either.  If you click on a link and then 'back-arrow' your browser to the reputation page, the highlighting is gone.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the highlighting is showing you what's changed since you last viewed the page. If you follow a link and then go back to the rep page, nothing has changed since you last viewed it, so the highlighting is gone.

Comment: @Gabe, In FF, if you back-arrow to the previous page, the highlighting is still there.  This is really important, so you can check each highlight, go back and check the next one, without losing your place.  If you refresh that page, then you would lose the highlighting, that's the magic of the back-arrow.

Comment: Are you saying that if you click on a link and then go back to the rep page, it will show any rep you gained while you were off the page highlighted *along with* whatever was highlighted when you first visited it?

Comment: @Gabe, no if you back-arrow to the rep page after clicking on a link, it will show you what you were looking at before you clicked on the link (in FF).  I don't think it 'updates' at all, so I don't think you'd see any rep that posted in the intervening time unless you refreshed.  I haven't had that situation happen since they implemented the highlighting, so I can't be completely sure on that.

Comment: If you go to the rep page and it doesn't show you your current rep, that would sounds like a bug in FF.

Comment: @Gabe, No, it's just way I'd expect browsers to work.  I back-arrow to pages all the time without them getting refreshed, and I like it that way, since it gives me the ability to check on multiple links without worrying about it changing on me.  I do that with Google every day.

Comment: I'm seeing HTTP headers that say `Cache-Control: public, max-age=0`. To me, the `max-age=0` part means that the cache of that page is always stale, so it should always be refreshed. If FF is showing you a stale cache, that sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @Gabe, Then Google has the same bug.

Comment: If a browser is showing you a stale page, the bug is in the browser, not the web site.

Comment: @Gabe, NO, that's not how browsers work, they are not supposed to (and don't) update a page when you 'back arrow' to it.  They are supposed to 'by design' show you __exactly__ what they had before.  Of course this isn't 100% with some dynamic content.  It would be browser hell, to not be able to go back the page you were looking at.

Comment: Do you have some reference to a document indicating what the correct behavior is? I'd like to see how you know that browsers are supposed to do.

Comment: @Gabe, I think using browsers since before the beginning (Gopher) has shown me a few things.  __The real evidence is that is what browsers currently do.__  If you want to change the behavior of all the browsers out there, then go for it.

Comment: So how many pages in the history stack is a browser required to cache past their expiration time?

Comment: @Gabe, no idea, but I often go back many pages to see one in it's original form.

Comment: The block instead of arrow thing has nothing to do with IE. It's just a question of fonts.

Comment: @balpha, see the OP's update.  So does Firefox load it's own fonts instead of using XPs?

Comment: @balpha: Why not use a 17px image instead of font? I can tell you that I have the font installed in Windows XP SP3 and I am running Office 2003. The issue still exists.

Comment: This issue still exists. I guess it's not a priority.

Comment: @0A0D, yep, I still see it in some places and just ignore it now.