# Arrow next to username shows as empty block, not as arrow in Firefox

Tags: support, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arrow next to username shows as empty block, not as arrow in IE8 and Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85654/arrow-next-to-username-shows-as-empty-block-not-as-arrow-in-ie8-and-firefox)

[image: screenshot]

Similar to [Arrow next to username shows as empty block, not as arrow in IE8 and Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85654/arrow-next-to-username-shows-as-empty-block-not-as-arrow-in-ie8). I see the problem with Firefox 6.0.2, Windows Vista 64 bit (don't ask), Office 2010 installed.

Comment: really, really? office 2010? what does that have anything to do with your browser??  (or does it....)

Comment: @Neal: It installs the Arial Unicode MS font that might not be included with the OS (as per Jeff's answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85654/arrow-next-to-username-shows-as-empty-block-not-as-arrow-in-ie8-and-firefox/85716#85716 ) I just wanted to cover that base, that's all.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this isn't a dupe (Vista vs XP for one thing..), but something has to be wacky on your box, honestly. Can you try on another computer?

Answer (score 1):

It is proably because of bad encoding. Read answer in question you have linked. Try to change browser's encoding

Comment: SO/MSO et al should (and do) include encoding as UTF-8 in its HTTP header, which my browser is agreeing to. Unless I'm mistaken.